# Undo Android 4.0 (aka Ice Cream Sandwich) Full Disk Encryption

Tags: settings, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, encryption

Just upgraded my Nexus S to Android 4 aka Ice Cream Sandwich. Was looking through all the new features, and decided to enable encryption, which worked (and is working) just fine. Now I'm wondering if I can undo that and revert to an un-encrypted filesystem.

There does not seem to be an option in the settings area, and while I'm not fussed about doing a factory reset, I just wonder if I'm missing an obvious option somewhere. Can anyone help? Or even confirm that the factory reset is the only way out?

Comment: I just got my Galaxy Nexus, and was thinking about turning on full disk encryption... until I saw your question. Why do you want to undo it? Have you encountered any issues with it?

Comment: No issues at all. This was just a result of my "Hey, I didn't read the warning screens properly and now I'm curious that there is no undo button" attitude :D

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There should have been a warning when you begin the encryption that you had to agree to. The only way to unencrypt it is to perform a factory reset, thereby wiping your data partition completely.

[image]

Comment: Ah, so there is. Thanks! PS Isn't the new screenshot shortcut awesome!

Comment: @scuzzy-delta: It's great for posting answers on this site, definitely :)

Comment: A description of how to perform that factory reset would be helpful.  I tried the the "factory reset" option in my custom recovery image, TWRP, and that did not seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 8):

I'm using Samsung Galaxy Note Android 4.0.3. and I've tried Encrypting and Decrypting several times successfully.

[image: Samsung Note ICS Decryption]

Comment: That's a Samsung add-on.

Comment: A downvote for sharing my knowledge/experience :( if only i could post my screenshots on how I Undo my Disk Encryptions.

Comment: Wasn't me :) I just pointed out that it's not part of AOSP. That's why I hate it that downvotes are anon.

Comment: @richard im not saying you gave me a downvote :) no problem :) im just expressing how some people votes without considerations :)

Comment: I added a screenshot on how I decrypt or undo encrypt my device.  thanks for the upvote that lifted my restriction for posting pictures. sorry guys i dont know how to make the image smaller.