# Cannot access internal memory due to cyanogenmod encryption, how can i decrypt the device?

Tags: cyanogenmod, encryption

I have ran into a small problem with my android tablet, it is a samsung galaxy tab 8.9 p7310

About a year ago i rooted it and installed CWM + CyanogenMod 9; i also encrypted the tablet. When i go under security the encrypted button is grey and i cannot click it, when i go to disable pin/password lock to none i cannot click on them and it says disabled by admin,encryption, credentials...

I cannot update my ROM because the SDCARD is encrypted and recovery cannot mount it so i am looking into alternatives, how can i format the internal memory in such a way as to reload the ROM; i don't care about the data stored on the device.
I have looked into nvflash but i am unsure how it would help me, is there an ADB format command?

if anyone can point me in a direction it would be much appreciated!

thank you :)

Comment: You should be able to do it with a factory reset: [Undo Android 4.0 (aka Ice Cream Sandwich) Full Disk Encryption](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17224)

Comment: i've done that and then during reboot it still asks me for my pin/password meaning the tablet is still encrypted, i am still unable to access the internal memory (/sdcard) from CWM

Comment: You can try to format it in CWM. PS: upgrading would have worked with a newer cwm 6.0, hat offers the 'adb sideload' command. Also, it would've worked this way: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19286/will-a-custom-recovery-work-with-an-encrypted-device/23879#23879

Comment: hmm i have samsung galaxy tab 8.9 (gt-p7300) and i dont see CWM 6 available for it on xda.developers :/